# R - Efficiently create dataframe from large raster excluding NA values

Tags: r, performance, gis, raster

apologies for cross-posting something similar in the GIS stack.

I am looking for a more efficient way to create a frequency table based on a large raster in R.

Currently, I have a few dozen rasters, ~ 150 million cells in each, and I need to create frequencies tables for each. These rasters are derived from masking a base raster with a few hundred small sampling locations*.  Therefore the rasters I am creating the tables from contain ~99% NA values.

My current working approach is this:

```
    sampling_site_raster <- raster("FILE")
    base_raster <- raster("FILE")

    sample_raster <- mask(base_raster, sampling_site_raster)

    DF <- as.data.frame(freq(sample_raster, useNA='no', progress='text'))

    ### run time for the freq() process ###
    user  system elapsed 
    162.60    4.85  168.40
```

this uses the `freq()` function from the raster package of R. The `usaNA=no` flag will dump the NA values.

My questions are:

1) is there a more efficient way to create a frequency table from a large raster that is 99% NA values? 
or 
2) is the a more efficient way to derive the values from the base raster than by using `mask()`? (using the Mask GP function in ArcGIS is very fast, but still has the NA values and is an extra step

*additional info: The sample areas represented by `sampling_site_raster` are irregular shapes of various sizes spread randomly across the study area.  In the `sampling_site_raster` the sampling sites are encoded as `1` and non-sampling areas as `NA`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mask the raster by raster, you will always get another huge raster. I don't think this is a way to make things faster.

What I would do is to try to mask by polygon layer using `extract`:

```
res <- extract(raster, polygons)
```

Then you will have all the cell values for each polygon and can run `freq` on them.

Comment: Thanks Tomas.  I do like the idea of just using extract, but as mentioned, the sampling sites are numerous and irregular polygons.  To get the coordinates to use for the extract function, I guess I would need to bring in the sample sites as a shapefile is read out the polygon geometry.

Comment: @user10553, exactly. But in case of very big rasters and very sparse sampling sites, I guess it could be faster. The best would of course be if you could partition the raster and the appropriate sampling sites and do it per partes. This is **much** faster (memory, caches...) - personal experience